# ORACLE SQL Range of hours

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, date-range

i have a problem, i have a table with 3 columns

```
- date - varchar2   - varchar2 -   
| date | start_hour | end_hour |
```

I need to make a validation to not overlap hour ranges.
For example:

```
| date  | start_hour | end_hour |  
| date1 | 09:00AM    | 09:30AM  |  
| date1 | 10:30AM    | 11:30AM  |  
| date1 | 01:00PM    | 03:00PM  |
```

Assuming the date is the same for the 3 rows.
What i need is, to no overlap these ranges
I cant insert a ranges like this
 start_hour =  08:00AM and end_hour = 09:20AM, because, a range between 09:00AM and 09:30AM already exist, so, the new range clashes with the range who exist in the table.
I tried so many querys, with not between, the end_hour i insert need to be less than the start_hour from a table.
Anyone have an idea how to do it?

Comment: What is the data type of your columns?  Oracle does not have a `time` data type.

Comment: I forgot to put it, is varchar2

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: First, I would tell you to store these in 24-hour format rather than AM/PM so the values can be correctly ordered.

Comment: Hi, APC, it's 18.0

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff, i already changed it, but i have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i already found the solution to my problem, as a recomendation from a comment in my question, when i changed the format of the hours, and the format of the new hours, it worked perfectly.
Here is the code for someone who have this same issue in the future.

```
DECLARE
  l_count NUMBER(1) := 0;
BEGIN

  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO   l_count
  FROM   table
  WHERE  start_hour <= :new_start_hour
  AND    end_hour   >= :new_end_hour
  AND    date = :date
  AND    ROWNUM     = 1;
  dbms_output.put_line(l_count);

END;
/
```

Thanks for all our help.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have converted your time format to `hh24:mi`

maybe this could help:

```
with tab as(
select 'date1' as dat,  '09:00' as  start_hour, '09:30' as end_hour from dual union all
select 'date1' as dat,  '10:30' as  start_hour, '11:30' as end_hour from dual union all
select 'date1' as dat,  '13:00' as  start_hour, '15:00' as end_hour from dual 
)
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM   tab
  WHERE  start_hour <= '09:10' --:new_end_hour
  AND    end_hour   >= '07:00' --:new_start_hour
  AND    dat = 'date1'
  ;
```

or you can use `between` to check it `start_hour` or  `end_hour` ist between the values

```
with tab as(
select 'date1' as dat,  '09:00' as  start_hour, '09:30' as end_hour from dual union all
select 'date1' as dat,  '10:30' as  start_hour, '11:30' as end_hour from dual union all
select 'date1' as dat,  '13:00' as  start_hour, '15:00' as end_hour from dual 
)
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM   tab
  WHERE  ('09:00' between start_hour and end_hour
  or    '09:10' between start_hour and end_hour
  )
  AND    dat = 'date1'
  ;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4211952faef8e6c1f390047c48cb354a)*

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, i already foun the solution and i asnwered it, i really appreciate your help!